# Como aguardar o retorno de uma informação usando Firebase Realtime DataBase

Tags: banco-de-dados, firebase

Estou tendo problemas em trabalhar com dados assíncronos do Firebase Database

Eu preciso identificar o tipo de usuário logado:

public static String getTipoUsuario(){
        Usuario usuario = consultarUsuario();
        return usuario.getTipo();
        }

```
public static Usuario consultarUsuario(){

    DatabaseReference firebaseRef = ConfiguracaoFirebase.getFirebase();
    DatabaseReference usuario = firebaseRef.child("usuarios").child(getIdUsuario());

    usuario.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.exists()){
                usuarioLogado = dataSnapshot.getValue(Usuario.class);
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            System.out.println("The read failed: " + databaseError.getCode());
        }
    });

    return usuarioLogado;
}
```

O que acontece é que o método sempre retorna NULL, pois o aplicativo executa o código antes do retorno da informação do banco de dados.

Como posso fazer para que o retorne somente com a certeza da consulta ter sido feita ?

Comment: Onde voce ta criando essa variavel usuarioLogado?

Comment: Variável global de uma Classe UsuarioFirebase para pegar informações do usuário